# Separate Exception mapping for REST web service / Web UI service

Tags: java, exception, jersey, jax-rs

I have written a web service with **Jersey**.
This web service provides both REST methods to be accessed via a *REST* client, and a User *WebUI* (basically simple HTML).

Those two aspects are served by 2 separate"Restlet" classes.

I have registered a unique Exception mapper that prints the whole error and stack trace whenever an unexpected exception happens. Those exceptions can be thrown either by the REST service or the WebUI.

I would like to return a plain text stack trace whenever the exception is returned to a REST client, and a pretty HTML error page whenever it happens on the WebUI side.

I thought I could do that by exploring the "Accepts" Http headers of the request, looking for HTML mime type. But the request is not available in the **ExceptionMapper** interface.

How would you do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this for an idea:

Write a servlet filter/listener that stores the HTTP request object in a Thread Local variable which you can then read from your exception mapper.

NB: In Spring this would be the achieved using either the [RequestContextFilter](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) or the [RequestContextListener](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html)

which would be added in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and used like this:

```
ServletRequestAttributes reqAttr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest req = reqAttr.getRequest();
```

If you are not using spring, then the source code may give you an idea on how to roll your own.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This solution is kind of brutal - I'd go with what Santiago suggests. In your mapper you can send your exception as the message entity and then have a message body writter for the exception type that serializes either using html or using plain text depending on the media type in the header.

Answer (score 1):

An ExceptionMapper maps an Exception to a Response, and the Response is then processed as if it had been returned by the resource method. It follows that if the response returns a bean as its entity and no media type, the algorithm in section 3.8 of the JAX-RS spec will take affect.

In summary, what you can do is the following:

1. Define a bean (or use the exception type itself as a bean)
2. Define MBW for the bean for the media types you want to return (text/html, application/json, text/plain)
3. ExceptionMapper returns Response that contains instance of bean (but no media type)

The JAX-RS runtime will then use the Accept header to produce the correct response (i.e. pick your MessageBodyWritter to produce the response).

If additional info from the request is still needed in the mapper itself, the only solution I see is to create your own exception, inject Request in your resource class, and include a reference to the request in the exception that you throw.

Hope this helps.

-- Santiago